# Wildfly: Error getting reflective information for class

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am dealing with two Eclipse Project. The former includes some Session Beans that I manage to deploy on  Wildfly Servr. The Latter includes a Servlet I need to inject and use the bean.

This is the structure of the projects containing the session bean. Projects is the session bean I want to use as Session Facade to interact with the Project JPA entity.

[image]

This is the servlet Injecting the Session bean. ProjectsLocal is its Local interface.

```
@EJB
private ProjectsLocal projects;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    projects.createProject("TestProject");
    String res = projects.getAllProjects();
    System.out.println(res);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/projects.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

This is the web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
   <ejb-local-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>Projects</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <local-home>entities.ProjectsLocal</local-home>
    <local>myBeans.BeanA</local>
  </ejb-local-ref>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>administrator</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/twp/Login/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>school</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

I get his error when deploying the web appliction: **Error getting reflective information for class servlet.Projects**

Comment: Is there a reason not to include the EJB library in the WAR deployment?

Answer (score 0):

With Reference to this [article](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7). The **Class loading** in JBoss AS7+ is considerably different to previous versions of JBoss AS.
Class loading is based on the JBoss Modules project. Instead of the more familiar hierarchical class loading environment, AS7's class loading is based on modules that have to define explicit dependencies on other modules.

**Ear deployments** are multi-module deployments. This means that not all classes inside an ear will necessarily have access to all other classes in the ear, unless explicit dependencies have been defined. **By default** the `EAR/lib` directory is a single module, and every WAR or EJB jar deployment is also a separate module.

Refer to the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in the article for an ear deployment.